# How to release UIImageView in UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I have UIImage outlet in TableViewCell which I will use it later in UITableView. When I check this in instruments I get some memory leak on UIImageView. I'm not releasing the UIImageView in the UITableViewCell, because I get exc_bad_access if I release it in the tavleViewCell.

My question is where do I release this UIImageView?

**Update**

CustomCell.h

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
IBOutlet UIImageView *customImage;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *customImage;

@end
```

CustomViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell.customImage.hidden = [[self.customImageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];

return cell; 
}
```

Comment: As I understand, you are using a UITableViewCell subclass.you should pst it's code, including the interface definition.

Comment: You should be releasing objects that the cell owns in the cell's dealloc.  That release should not get an exception.  If you are getting an exception then something is wrong with the retain/release balance in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView caches cells for later reuse.  That shows up as a memory leak but you can eventually reuse the cell so it is not really leaked.

What you can do is release the imageview that is retained by your custom UITableViewCell when the cell scrolls off screen, but that could lead to performance problems if the image is needed again when scrolling.

Comment: I guess this explains the issue. Thank you, I will leave it as it is.

Comment: As long as you don't give us more informations, this answer is just an assumption.

Comment: I did track down apparant memory leaks in my own app only to find out the that the only remaining retain on my UITableViewCells were from the UITableView, and it retained the cells even after they scrolled off the screen and were no longer visible.  But yes, it is only an assumption that this is what is happening for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's define what you mean. When we're talking about a true memory leak, that's when heap has been allocated but there are no longer any pointers to it anywhere in your code. It is truly leaked, lost, and cannot be reused. If the Leaks tool identifies it as a leak that means that it is this kind of leak, which is not something to just live with and not a false leak as some have suggested.

If you don't see it in the Leaks tool, then it could still be a leak or may be another type of memory issue which some also refer to as a memory leak, such as abandoned memory.

In any case, please let us know what makes you call it a leak and you need to post your code for more help.

Answer (score -1):

try setting it to `nil` i.e in dealloc:

```
self.imageViewName = nil;
```

Comment: Ok, then it's time to share some code so we know what you talking about because it sounds straight forward

Comment: You should never reference self in dealloc. Instead of self.imageViewName = nil use [imageViewName release]; imageViewName = nil;

Comment: Not true, if you synthesized your property it's common practice. The setter that was created by synthesizing a property will take care of releasing that property. i.e `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *timestamp;` will produce the following setter `- (void)setTimestamp:(NSDate *)newValue
{
  if (timestamp != newValue)
  {
    [timestamp release];
    timestamp = [newValue retain];
  }
}`